# Is it possible to use CSS to group radio buttons rendered by RadioButtonList with their labels?

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, kentico

We're working with a CMS (Kentico) which internally uses an ASP.NET webforms `RadioButtonList` to render radio buttons on custom forms. Via the CMS we can still control the `RepeatDirection` and `RepeatLayout` properties of this control but little else.

The requirement is to display the radios horizontally so `RepeatDirection` **Horizontal** and `RepeatLayout` **Flow** achieves this. However the rendered markup is just an alternating list of `<input />` and `<label />` elements.

The problem arises at narrow device widths when the radio button list starts to wrap. The `<input />` and `<label />` elements wrap individually so you lose the visual grouping between control and label.

Since we can't affect the markup directly, what option do we have to simulate an HTML grouping? I fear this may be a JS-only solution which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you need custom HTML markup, you should consider to use a normal SELECT element with normal OPTION elements (or any kind of markup you may need).

You could use the runat="server" attribute together with an id on these elements as well if you need some handlers or server interaction. ASP handles this as web controls (see System.Web.UI namespace).
Another option would be to hide the standard ASP control and set the hidden values via Javascript if the options in your custom markup change. This is also a very nice solution if you need to style some fency custom radios.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But as question stated, I don't have control over the markup, only the CSS. And I was hoping to avoid a JS solution.

Comment: Hi. You could "clone" the original Kentico Web Part. If you do this, choose "clone files" as well.
After this you could edit the Web Part Markup according to your needs without changing the original Web Part.
I think it will be very hard to find a solution without DOM manipulation with JS if you do not want to edit the markup.